Pyprocar: Spin texture at an off-gamma high-symmetry point
I would like to know how to get the spin texture of a material at an off-gamma high-symmetry point, say L (0.5, 0, 0.5) for hexagonal systems. I understand that there is a tag "k_z_plane" in pyprocar which tells which K_z plane to generate a 2d fermi surface. By default, it is zero, whereas for my case, I can change it to 0.5 as per the coordinates of the L-point. I have the following questions related to the scripts for 2d-k mesh generation and 2d fermi surface as implemented in pyprocar:
1.How should I generate the 2d k-mes (k_x-k_y plane) in such a case?
2.Are there any other changes (except k_z_plane tag) to be done in the script of pyprocar to generate the spin texture?
Thanks.
Pradhi
